# get image by his url with any prefix

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an image on my site by adress http://example.com/assets/gallery/11/65.jpg
I want to have acces to this image by url
siteadress/assets/gallery/11/image_65.jpg or
siteadress/assets/gallery/11/anytext_65.jpg
(siteadress=http://example.com/, i write like this because i can not post more than two links)
i tried this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/assets/gallery/([0-9]*)/(.*)([0-9]*)\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^/assets/gallery/([0-9]*)/(.*)([0-9]*)\.(.*)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/assets/gallery/$1/$3 [QSA,L]
```

but this did not work

what rule i must write to mod_rewrite?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in your web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^gallery/(\d+)/[^_]+_(\d+).jpg assets/gallery/$1/$2.jpg [L]
```

This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`

Comment: yes, this work, with some changes: RewriteRule ^assets/gallery/(\d+)/[^_]+_(\d+).jpg assets/gallery/$1/$2.jpg [L] instead of RewriteRule ^gallery/(\d+)/[^_]+_(\d+).jpg assets/gallery/$1/$2.jpg [L] thanks